# Best verb to use for formation in strategy formation

Tags: meaning, verbs

I am writing an article about strategy formation and have trouble finding the right verbs. For instance, I would like to say something about the process of forming a strategy but have some serious doubts about using 'forming'. Would there be a better word, formating for instance?

I had a hard time looking for duplicates, since strategy as well as formation are very often used in a different context. My excuses if the answer to this question is already somewhere I did not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- **conceive**: *"It was difficult to conceive a strategy that countered their negative campaign."*
- **formulate**: *"We didn't have a lot of time to formulate a strategy."*
- **come up with** (informal)" *"We couldn't come up with a new strategy for the product  launch."*
- **think of/up** (informal): *"We couldn't think of [/up] a good strategy to increase market share."*

Comment: Thank you, formulate is what I will use, although conceive would also be suitable, in this case it is more about putting it on paper so formulate would be my winner.

Answer (score 0):

One choice is *formulate, formulating, formulation. Craft* is a strong word meaning *to make* and suggests care, skill, or quality, though it has been used so much in recent years that people may feel it losing it's power.

https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=define+formulate&oq=define+formulate&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5980j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8